# Why do I have to double escape a dot inside a regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

In c++11, if I want to match all txt files starting with only lower characters e.g. `[a-z]+\.txt` writing in regular expression syntax, why do I have to use double escape which is

```
std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");
```

Is there any special meaning for `\.` in C++?

Comment: You’re not double-escaping the dot. You’re escaping the escape character.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no special meaning for `\.` in c++. However, there is a special meaning for `\`, which is an escape sequence in c++ (the same as for a regex). So you need to escape the `.` so that the regex treats it as a literal `.`. Then you need *another* `\` for c++ itself, to escape the `\`.

You can avoid the escape for c++, by using [raw-string-literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), like this:

```
std::regex txt_regex(R"([a-z]+\.txt)");
                           // ^ only the escape for . is needed
```

Comment: I understood. I have to escape backslash otherwise it means simply a escape character. Thanks!

Comment: @潘樾阳 No problem :) If this answers your question, consider accepting it.